Setting Language Service in Custom Editor not working
Currently, I have implemented a custom editor that is configured to display any .cs file in Visual Studio using my editor. The editor does underline squiggles for syntax errors and "dulls out" unused 'using' statements at the top, indicating some understanding of C#. However, the displayed text lacks any syntax coloring. I aim to make the file appear as it would in the traditional Visual Studio code editor, with complete syntax coloring. I believe this can be achieved by setting the language service for the text buffer. Although the SetLanguageServiceID function returns 0, indicating it was called correctly, the syntax highlighting is still not working. I used this Guid for the C# language: 694DD9B6-B865-4C5B-AD85-86356E9C88DC but am not sure if it is correct. Commenting out the setting of the language service does not change anything, so I predict that the association of my custom editor factory with the .cs file extension might come with some of the features automatically. Below is my implemented editor factory:
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop;
using IOleServiceProvider = Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost;

namespace CustomTextEditorFactory
{
    [Guid("F86E3EAF-07DF-40CD-8E4A-6C01BA7E2BAF")]
    internal class CustomEditorFactory : IVsEditorFactory
    {
        private ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly Package _package;

        public CustomEditorFactory(Package package)
        {
            _package = package ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));
        }

        public int SetSite(IOleServiceProvider psp)
        {
            _serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider(psp);
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
        }

        public int MapLogicalView(ref Guid rguidLogicalView, out string pbstrPhysicalView)
        {
            pbstrPhysicalView = null;
            if (rguidLogicalView == VSConstants.LOGVIEWID_Primary ||
                rguidLogicalView == VSConstants.LOGVIEWID_Code)
            {
                return VSConstants.S_OK;
            }
            return VSConstants.E_NOTIMPL;
        }

        public int Close()
        {
            _serviceProvider?.Dispose();
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int CreateEditorInstance(
            uint grfCreateDoc,
            string pszMkDocument,
            string pszPhysicalView,
            IVsHierarchy pvHier,
            uint itemid,
            IntPtr punkDocDataExisting,
            out IntPtr ppunkDocView,
            out IntPtr ppunkDocData,
            out string pbstrEditorCaption,
            out Guid pguidCmdUI,
            out int pgrfCDW)
        {
            ppunkDocView = IntPtr.Zero;
            ppunkDocData = IntPtr.Zero;
            pbstrEditorCaption = null;
            pguidCmdUI = Guid.Empty;
            pgrfCDW = 0;

            // Found some sort of factory that is able to create a VsTextBuffer object
            IComponentModel compMod = GetService(typeof(SComponentModel)) as IComponentModel;
            IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService adapterFactory = compMod.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();
            IVsTextBuffer textBuffer = adapterFactory.CreateVsTextBufferAdapter(GetService(typeof(IOleServiceProvider)) as IOleServiceProvider);

            // add file content to the text buffer
            string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(pszMkDocument);
            textBuffer.InitializeContent(fileContent, fileContent.Length);

            // set the language service for the text buffer for syntax highlighting
            Guid languageServiceGuid = new Guid("{694DD9B6-B865-4C5B-AD85-86356E9C88DC}");
            int result = textBuffer.SetLanguageServiceID(ref languageServiceGuid);

            // CodeWindow object contains IVsTextLines for its text buffer so cast the buffer as such
            IVsTextLines textLines = (IVsTextLines)textBuffer;


            Type codeWindowType = typeof(IVsCodeWindow);
            Guid riid = codeWindowType.GUID;
            Guid clsid = typeof(VsCodeWindowClass).GUID;
            IVsCodeWindow codeWindow = (IVsCodeWindow)_package.CreateInstance(ref clsid, ref riid, codeWindowType);

            codeWindow.SetBuffer(textLines);

            // Obtain the primary view managed by the CodeWindow object (we set the buffer but not the text view)
            IVsTextView primaryView;
            codeWindow.GetPrimaryView(out primaryView);

            // set output parameters for VS
            ppunkDocView = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(codeWindow);
            ppunkDocData = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(textLines);
            pbstrEditorCaption = "Custom!!!";
            pguidCmdUI = Guid.Empty;
            pgrfCDW = 0;

            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }
    }
}


And here is my package file (this is a VSIX project)
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

namespace CustomTextEditorFactory
{
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
    [ProvideEditorExtension(typeof(CustomEditorFactory), ".cs", 700)]
    [Guid(RenderCustomTextEditorPackage.PackageGuidString)]
    public sealed class RenderCustomTextEditorPackage : AsyncPackage
    {
        public const string PackageGuidString = "AF177B7B-8E7C-4F93-B0B6-AC5670B94080";

        #region Package Members

        protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
        {
            await this.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);

            // Register the editor factory
            this.RegisterEditorFactory(new CustomEditorFactory(this));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}


Program.cs (example file with an error to showcase issue)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSVN
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // hello world
            // Starting fresh with new code
            int hello
        }
    }
}

I have tried setting the language service of textLines itself but that did not change anything. I also have tried setting the language service before and after content initialization.
Note on reproducing code: Create C# VSIX project in VS, add a class (CustomEditorFactory) to the project, copy and paste code provided. Simply hit f5 (or start) and Visual Studio should open up an experimental instance that allows you to debug. View the code of any .cs file to use the custom editor. If you choose to reproduce this code, I set the priority of my custom editor to be 700, so Visual Studio will most likely open ALL of your .cs files with this custom editor from here on out. To get rid of this I reset my experimental instance completely but there are probably other ways to reverse this.
